# Gracefully exiting emacs while afplay is running

Tags: osx, emms, exit

When I exit emacs while my music is playing using afplay -- music keeps playing.

What is the right way of stopping/killing afplay process?

Should I use exit hooks or is there emms built-in setting I can tinker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with adding a kill emacs hook:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'emms-stop)
```

And it solves the problem for me.